# FluorineFx: Client_onConnect does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

```
namespace TinyChat
{
    class Program
    {
        NetConnection Client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program TinyChat_Function = new Program();
            TinyChat_Function.connectTinyChat();
        }
        void connectTinyChat()
        {
            Client = new NetConnection();
            Client.OnConnect += new ConnectHandler(Client_OnConnect);
            Client.NetStatus += new NetStatusHandler(Client_NetStatus);

            Client.Connect("rtmp://209.212.144.77:443/tinyconf", new string[] { "SomeRoom", "none", "show", "tinychat" }); 
        }
    }
```

Errors:

```
1 The name 'Client_OnConnect' does not exist in the current context
2 The name 'Client_netStatus' does not exist in the current context
```

Using latest version of FluorineFx.

The documentation shows that this is the right way to do this, but this does not work. Any ideas on how i can solve this problem?

[The documentation can be found here.](http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/fluorine/netconnectionrtmp.html)

Comment: Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the code for the `Client_OnConnect`event handler and the `Client_NetStatus`event handlers? You are **adding** the events here in your lines , but you didn't **implement** the code. Unless you forgot to paste it in the question.

```
Client.OnConnect += new ConnectHandler(Client_OnConnect);
Client.NetStatus += new NetStatusHandler(Client_NetStatus);
```

You   if you look at the documentation link this is the code

```
void netConnection_OnConnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //The NetConnection object is connected now
    netConnection.Call("serverHelloMsg", new ServerHelloMsgHandler(), "some text");
}
```

You should replace `netConnection_OnConnect` to `Client_OnConnect` and write the code in the method, maybe like this

```
void Client_OnConnect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


 //handle connection below and do whatever needs to be done

}
```